# Regex- grab between: right boundary not escaped

Tags: regex, r

I wish to extract information from a series of R .Rd files.  I want the examples (though this could be any tex tag) and want to extract between a left tex tag and the closing curly brace.  I want to also grab closing curly braces that are escaped in some way (`[}]` or `\\}`, or any way I'm not thinking about).

So here I have a sample and my attempt to extract but it captures only upto the first escaped curly brace:

```
## fake tex
x <- "Here we go \\example{ x <- 6\ngsub(\"\\}\", \"\", x, perl=TRUE)\ngsub(\"[}]\", \"\", x, perl=TRUE)\n}\n\\end{here}"

## regex to extract
regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?<=\\\\example\\{)([^}]*)(?=\\})", x, perl = TRUE))
```

**Current output**

```
[[1]]
[1] " x <- 6\ngsub(\"\\"
```

**desired output**

```
" x <- 6\ngsub(\"\\}\", \"\", x, perl=TRUE)\ngsub(\"[}]\", \"\", x, perl=TRUE)\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to first get rid of the escaped curly braces and then put them back at the end:

```
x <- gsub("\\\\}","\001",x)
x <- gsub("\\[}\\]","\002",x)
match <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?<=\\\\example\\{)([^}]*)(?=\\})", x, perl = TRUE))
match <- gsub("\001","\\\\}",match)
match <- gsub("\002","[}]",match)
```

This gives

```
> match
[1] " x <- 6\ngsub(\"\\}\", \"\", x, perl=TRUE)\ngsub(\"[}]\", \"\", x, perl=TRUE)\n"
```

Comment: Nice thinking.  I'll see if others come up with additional responses or  critiques to this approach. +1

Comment: It would indeed be nice if there was a way of actually matching what you want in a single regex call without any detours...

Answer (score 0):

The following gives the desired output, at least with the example you gave :

```
> gsub(".+example\\{(.+)}.+","\\1",x)
[1] " x <- 6\ngsub(\"\\}\", \"\", x, perl=TRUE)\ngsub(\"[}]\", \"\", x, perl=TRUE)\n"
```